# Spring book throws Field postRepository in required a bean of type 'repository.PostRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am aware that there are a lot of questions related to the same but none of them worked for some reason. Hence, posting the same and hoping to get some response.

I am trying to follow the `SpingBoot application` tutorial from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRfivQ90vcs&list=PL0hWUTMmCidOaSSvd_adRr-vh19jZQKkr) and build the same application. But for some reason I get following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field postRepository in com.testingconverter.service.PostService required a bean of type 'com.testingconverter.repository.PostRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.testingconverter.repository.PostRepository' in your configuration.
```

Following are my classes:

1. `Main SpringBootApplication` class:

```
package com.testingconverter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestingConverterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestingConverterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2. `Controller` class:

```
package com.testingconverter.controller;

import com.testingconverter.entities.PostEntity;
import com.testingconverter.service.PostService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/posts")
    public List<PostEntity> posts() {
        return postService.getAllPost();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/posts")
    public void publishPost(@RequestBody PostEntity post) {
        postService.insert(post);
    }
}
```

3. My `Entity` class:

```
package com.testingconverter.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PostEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    private String body;

    private Date date;

}
```

4. My `Repository` class:

```
package com.testingconverter.repository;

import com.testingconverter.entities.PostEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<PostEntity, Long> {
}
```

5. My `Service` class:

```
package com.testingconverter.service;

import com.testingconverter.entities.PostEntity;
import com.testingconverter.repository.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    public List<PostEntity> getAllPost() {
        return postRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void insert(PostEntity post) {
        postRepository.save(post);
    }
}
```

I tried many things like adding the `@ComponentScan` etc but nothing seems to work for me. Can someone please explain to me what's going wrong here? How can I fix this?

Following is my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Remove your exclusion. It will not start a datasource, no datasource no entitymanagerfactory, no entitymanagerfactory no Spring Data JPA. Also please remove the `@Repository` from the interface (it hurts my eyes and adds nothing!).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot for the response and your time. As you mentioned I have just `@SpringBootApplication` and also, removed the `@Repository` from the `PostRepository` interface but I get following error now: `Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.`

Comment: You need a database else it won't work ofcourse add something like H2 for an in-memory database (which I'm sure they did in the tutorial as well, although not sure how smart it is to follow a 4 year old tutorial).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Now it's working. Actually, I was thinking if we are not using why to add the database. Maybe I should have looked a bit more carefully. Thanks for your time. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

You excluding default database configuration. Remove that exclude part and add your database configuration in application properties files.

If you going to exclude then you have to create you datasource in configuration file.

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = 
DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```